# Is there something wrong with heat pump + Empire furnace?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, heat-pump

I've been asked to look into A/C for a 1600 square foot building at our lodge.  The gas furnace is old and tired, and on its last legs. There is a top floor that is 2 rooms subdivided, and a well buried basement that is 1 big room and some offices. There are ducts and registers already installed in the basement; they put in a low, cheap drop ceiling to hide them, and it strangles the space. I would be happy to see the duct-o-pus go.

The locale is northern Ohio, and we have "sometimes too cold for heat pump" winters and power outages during those winters.

The goal is to have A/C and heat. *A key part of the plan is to have the **heat work even with AC power out*** and everyone I talk to seems to bounce over that last part.

And I'll be paying for this.

### The conventional advice

The advice I am consistently getting long and strong is "Just go cheap.  Get a lowball 13 SEER air conditioner, $3000".  I talk about higher efficiency or SEER rating and they say "the extra cost will never pay for itself".  When I try talking about heat pumps, they *really* scrunch up their face.

But... "That furnace is on its last legs" (believable), so let's go cheapo again and get the government minimum 80% efficiency gas furnace for $2500.

We're not done being cheap.  The ducted system needs electricity to push air around, so generator, and our members have other priorities during ice storms, so ATS needed ($1500).

But that needs a *bigger* generator since small ones don't play well with ATS's, so $5000 Generac type deal.

And since generators that large suck up a lot of gas, we'll need bigger gas lines.

I feel like I'm dealing with the mafia. *What next?*

### What I want

What I want (obviously) is a cold-climate heat pump because it's the 21st century, dammit! Either in a ducted or mini-split format, but I'd prefer mini-split.

For emergency heat, I want an [Empire style gravity convection wall furnace](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Williams-Monterey-Top-Vent-Wall-Heater-50-000-BTUH-70-AFUE-Natural-Gas-5009622A/311801074), which works on a thermocouple and millivolt thermostat.  They don't require electricity (they make it with the thermocouple).
Some mount in an interior wall with registers on both sides, and give about 50,000 BTU/hr.
Others mount in a single wall, with one side, and give about 35,000 BTU/hr.
They're about $800 bare unit, I assume about $1500 installed.

The Empire is wired to a millivolt thermostat that will call for heat when the electricity is out.  But that is in parallel with a 24V relay which is energized by the heat pump thermostat's "call for auxiliary heat". That allows the heat pump to call for it.

The space is laid out in a manner favorable to the Empire.  It's 2 rooms, not a maze, so stick it in an interior wall and you're done (i.e. at the point in the interior wall that the furnace stack already goes up).  The basement can either get heated through the floor and open stairwell, or get its own Empire.

### What's wrong with my plan?

That is to say, why isn't everyone recommending this to me, and pushing me into *That 70's* HVAC equipment instead?

What am I missing? What will go catastrophically wrong if I do the above?   Why a

(obviously all the work hired done since freon and gas are involved).

Comment: 1 - I'm big on Total Cost of Ownership. So I'd try to crunch the numbers based on HDD and CDD and past utility bills etc. to see the impact of higher efficiency over reasonable lifespan of the equipment  (10 to 20 years?); 2 - Sounds like a second heater in the basement is needed; 3 - What is the goal of heat when power out? Just to keep the pipes from freezing or to actually use the building? Because if it is actually to use the building then you may need a generator anyway, though smaller.

Comment: The goal of "heat when power out" is to prevent pipe freeze.  If the power is out, they'll have their own problems, and nobody *will have time* to be there.  One of my big variables is future cost of natural gas.  It really looks like the world is electrifying, and I'm not Republican enough to want to dig in my heels and go retro-tech merely to spite Al Gore.

Comment: While the end of oil & gas (due to supplies) and coal (due to lots of reasons) is "near", I would not expect the natural gas market in the US to dry up within the reasonable lifetime of an appliance installed today (or the next several years). If anything, natural gas will continue as the peaker plants for utility electricity - all the more necessary if thousands of EVs want to charge up in the middle of a hot summer day (Tesla's utility-level battery storage just can't scale that fast).  I'd actually expect the cost to stay level or go down as demand gradually lowers due to heat pumps

Comment: and other new technology. Piped natural gas (as opposed to a tank of propane) also doesn't have the storage costs of other fuels or the peak costs of electricity (which is mostly peak on summer afternoons but *also* on the coldest days).

Comment: And while it doesn't help for heating (totally unsafe to do so - every so often you hear of CO poisoning when people try), having a gas cooktop has been great when we've had power outages here (Maryland) due to hurricanes and both summer & winter storms. Fortunately very infrequent after the state forced Pepco to upgrade - several years ago replaced every line in my neighborhood, raised the lines up a bit (new poles in many cases), etc.

Comment: Actually, if cost of natural gas is an issue, your heat pump + no-power-furnace makes even more sense. If natural gas prices double, that won't be nearly as much of an impact as it would be if 6 months of the year you're burning gas for regular heat all day long.

Comment: I put in a 19 SEER heat pump about 10 years ago, it has variable speed blowers in and out. I installed a gas furnace instead of the resistance coils with the heat pump.  I also put in a whole house generator at the same time. When they checked the gas, the higher efficiency furnace reduced my gas requirements and I had enough for a generator. The system works great and I am in southern Michigan. I also have hydronic heat in two rooms, that works with gravity and a hot water heater but better when the small pump can run. If the gas fails I will get cold but other then that I will stay warm.